# additional modules for python in tkinter issue

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a tkinter app in python which requires a few python modules (for example paramiko) that need to be installed additionally.

When I will be done with the whole app and create an executable version of the app (.exe extension), and send this app to one of my friends' computer, can he run the app without having python, paramiko, etc. on his computer?

2nd question: What is the exe equivavelent in mac for that I could make my app runnable instantly (I think of some kind of portable version.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [Cx_Freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Yes the idea is to turn it into an application that can be run on computers without Python installed.  If it does not run correctly then the script has not been properly "frozen".

Cx_Freeze works on all major platforms as described in their front page (see link above for details) but you must freeze it on each platform you wish to develop for (Windows on Windows, Mac on a Mac and so on)  There is no executable that can run on all platforms.

There are alternatives such as Pyinstaller and Py2app.  The latter works only for Python 2 and is no longer maintained.  I would recommend Cx_Freeze or Pyinstaller because they are the only two still being maintained.

Pyinstaller is easier but cx_Freeze also offers a lot of options when building.

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick and useful answer!

Comment: @Marci  For the case of Linux (and Windows).  You can use VirtualBox to save the hassle of installing a new OS.  For Mac for legal reasons you need a Mac.  No problem.

Comment: Yeah, I have a laptop (windows), a mac (macos) and a raspberry pi(linux) so almost every os to test. Thx again!

Comment: @Marci There is no problem then.  It does really matter what device it works on as long as it has an OS that supports Python - even then you could get it working if you are building from the source.

Comment: Isn't pyinstaller being maintained as well?

Comment: @erocoar Your right see http://www.pyinstaller.org/development.html.  I've edited my answer